# WebView2 CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync issue with Fetch.continueRequest

Tags: c#, chromium, webview2

I'm using WebView2 in a .net 5 WPF app and have been playing with the devtools protocol as a means of intercepting specific requests for assets.  In looking at the Chrome dev docs (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), it's possible to intercept requests and then decide whether to continue them, cancel them or satisfy them yourself.

I've been able to successfully intercept the first web request (Eg. https:// [www.somedomain.tld](http://www.somedomain.tld)), but I've not been able to successfully continue the request (which would presumably trigger any other asset requests made as a result of the parsed html response).

After WebView initialization, I do the following (which works):

```
// Intercept requests
var receiver = webView.CoreWebView2.GetDevToolsProtocolEventReceiver("Fetch.requestPaused");
receiver.DevToolsProtocolEventReceived += FetchRequestPaused;
await webView.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Fetch.enable", "{}");
```

This is my event handler - which doesn't do what I'm expecting it to (although it doesn't deadlock now at least):

```
private void FetchRequestPaused(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2DevToolsProtocolEventReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(e.ParameterObjectAsJson);
   var id = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("requestId");
   var payload = $"{{\"requestId\":\"{id}.0\"}}";

   // We can't do this as an async call as it will try to post to the main thread, which is
   // busy waiting in this event handler, so we deadlock
   //_ = await webView.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Fetch.continueRequest", payload);

   // Exception: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   // var result = await webView.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Fetch.continueRequest", payload).ConfigureAwait(false);

   // PROBLEM: This invokes the call on the UI thread OK...
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
      // ...but it doesn't actually do anything
      webView.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Fetch.continueRequest", payload);
   }));
}
```

Not only does the requested page not finish loading, but the browser is left in an unusual state and so right-clicking on the control and selecting "Refresh" will crash - yielding a COMException:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (0x8007139F)'`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here or am missing??

Thanks!

**Additional information**

In swapping out the events for the deprecated `Network.setRequestInterception` / `Network.continueInterceptedRequest` equivalents, I'm seeing the same behaviour - which at least tells us that it's either a problem with my calling code (most likely) or a bug in WebView2 (possible) rather than Chromium.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I realised there were two problems.  The first is that my installed version of Edge was slightly behind.  The second was that my Action delegate was synchronous.  The call should read:

```
// Somebody forgot some 'async' keywords..!
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
{
   var x = await webView.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Fetch.continueRequest", payload);
}));
```